# How to show a directive based on value in repeater

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a repeater that loops through a list of types. Based on the type value it will show the corresponding directive. I have several directives called: dropdown, Long text, Choice, multichoice, etc. The repeater will loop through the list of types to show the matching directive

```
<div ng-repeat="field in model.Fields">
     <!-- if field = text then render longtext directive -->
     <!-- if field = dropdown then render dropdown directive -->
     <!-- if field = choice then render choice directive -->
     <!-- and so on -->
</div>
```

Is there an elegant way to do this? BTW, you can change the title of this message to a more appropriate title.

Comment: Probably something with `ng-if`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular's [`ng-switch`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch) directive may be more appropriate for this:

```
<div ng-repeat="field in model.Fields">
    <div ng-switch on="field">
        <div ng-switch-when="text" longtext>
            <!-- Render the longtext directive -->
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="dropdown" dropdown>
            <!-- Render the longtext directive -->
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="choice" choice>
            <!-- Render the longtext directive -->
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-default default>
            <!-- Render the default directive -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```